# Have a war contains application and quartz jobs in spring container everything depends on jboss-modules, deployed. application works but quartz fails

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, jboss-modules

**In our application till today we used a fat war with all libraries placed in the WEB-INF/lib in war, and it worked with no issues, But when we separate the dependencies in to jboss-modules (the application runs in spring container), and is deployed, and we were able to make rest calls successfully. but the application also has quartz jobs which are failing with below exception traces.**

> 11:43:30,586 WARN  [AppQuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to delete quartz job :: QuartzJob1 groupName :: DEFAULT QuartzJob1: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't obtain triggers for job: QuartzJob1 from [Module "com.mts.dependants:main" from local module loader @4eeba477 (roots: D:\3-DevEnv\jboss6.0.1\modules)] [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QuartzJob1 from [Module "com.mts.dependants:main" from local module loader @4eeba477 (roots: D:\3-DevEnv\jboss6.0.1\modules)]]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getTriggersForJob(JobStoreSupport.java:2144) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$28.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2130) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:245) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3723) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getTriggersForJob(JobStoreSupport.java:2127) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.getTriggersOfJob(QuartzScheduler.java:1476) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.deleteJob(QuartzScheduler.java:989) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.deleteJob(StdScheduler.java:301) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at AppQuartzScheduler.deleteMTSJob(AppQuartzScheduler.java:93) [classes:]
>           at AppQuartzScheduler.deleteOldAndscheduleMTSJobs(AppQuartzScheduler.java:70) [classes:]
>           at AppQuartzScheduler.initialize(AppQuartzScheduler.java:47) [classes:]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1696) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1635) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-2]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QuartzJob1 from [Module "com.mts.dependants:main" from local module loader @4eeba477 (roots: D:\3-DevEnv\jboss6.0.1\modules)]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1483) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1333) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1180) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(OracleDelegate.java:141) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1780) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTriggersForJob(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1704) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getTriggersForJob(JobStoreSupport.java:2141) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           ... 43 more
>
> 11:43:30,845 FATAL [AppQuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to schedule quartz job :: DEFAULTQuartzJob1: org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'DEFAULT.QuartzJob1', because one already exists with this identification.
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1108) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$2.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:1062) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3703) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3701) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:245) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1058) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:886) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
>           at AppQuartzScheduler.scheduleMTSJob(AppQuartzScheduler.java:79) [classes:]
>           at AppQuartzScheduler.deleteOldAndscheduleMTSJobs(AppQuartzScheduler.java:71) [classes:]
>           at AppQuartzScheduler.initialize(AppQuartzScheduler.java:47) [classes:]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1696) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1635) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-2]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1-JBPAPP6-1709.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]

## Application structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you split your app to modules? Did you enabled visibility/dependency between your modules in modules.xml? The classnotfound indicates that there may be some misconfiguration in your modules.

Comment: Before the war is a fat war with all third party jars in the lib, now i just moved all third party lib(spring jars, webservices jar, quartz jars and more) to a single module, and jbos-deployment-structure has a dependency on this module.

Comment: Did you move any config or whatsoever to this module? The log suggests that your dependency module tries to access class from your app (QuartzJob1)

Comment: No config changes, Application has three modules, web, module1, module2. In web we have the QuartzSchedulerManager defined, and the jobs reside in module2. and all these are our application specific.

And we just moved the third party lib out to modules.

(Please note log is modified not to show our application specific classes and package names, instead a dummy name)